# camel knative component not deploying any knative service for knative endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, apache-camel, knative, knative-serving

Added a camel-knative component in my camel route as an inbound but deployment on kubernetes cluster is not working. Expected it to expose a knative service corresponding to knative endpoint but give us an error of KnativeConsumerFactory not created.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-knative</artifactId>
   <version>${camel-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Route.java

```
from("knative:endpoint/schedulerInbound").process(..)
```

knative.json

```
 {
  "services": [
    {
      "type": "endpoint",
      "name": "schedulerInbound",
      "metadata": {
        "camel.endpoint.kind": "source"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

application.properties

```
camel.component.Knative.environment-path=classpath:knative.json
```

I have not mentioned any config related to knative service in kubernetes deployment manifest.